# NASM macros with "multi-line arguments"

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

That's probably not a great question title, but what I want to do is basically pass multiple lines of assembly to a nasm macro. Or, equivalently, I want a macro to implement the boilerplate "top" and "bottom" of some block of code, but have the middle be arbitrary.

As a concrete example, consider the following nasm source:

```
%assign regn 8
%rep 8
%define reg r %+ regn
lea reg, [rsp - 8]       ; body
push reg                 ; body
%assign regn (regn + 1)
%endrep
```

This loops over all the registers from `r8` to `r15`, and generates the two lines of "body" code for each one, with a result like:

```
lea    r8,[rsp-0x8]
push   r8
lea    r9,[rsp-0x8]
push   r9
lea    r10,[rsp-0x8]
push   r10
lea    r11,[rsp-0x8]
push   r11
lea    r12,[rsp-0x8]
push   r12
lea    r13,[rsp-0x8]
push   r13
lea    r14,[rsp-0x8]
push   r14
lea    r15,[rsp-0x8]
push   r15
```

I would like to extract this "loop over 8 register" boilerplate, which is all of the lines not marked `; body` above, into some kind of macro, so I could call it with different types of bodies.

If the body was only a single line, this would be as easy as:

```
%macro loop_r8_r15 1
%assign regn 8
%rep 8
%define reg r %+ regn
%1       ; body
%assign regn (regn + 1)
%endrep
```

I can't find a natural way to extend that to multiple lines, however. I guess I could use a macro that accepts one or more arguments and then "loop over" them in the body, but this means you need to write the macro call on a single line with every line pasted together rather than the natural one-line-per-instruction way you'd like to write it. I'm also not sure how it works if the body itself contains macro calls or other directives.

Comment: I don't know if that's possible with NASM's macro language.  I assume the example you cooked up was not real code, but if it was, you could do it more efficiently on Intel (without stack-sync uops) with `lea r9, [r8 - 0x8]` / `lea r10, [r8 - 0x10]` and so on.

Comment: @PeterCordes, actually it _is_ [real code](https://github.com/travisdowns/uarch-bench/commit/e320aae03f28903369e6f13ce08c29d2aa795a00#diff-8485929ddd759f9862831b87d83018c6R296) to test the pointer-chasing latency stuff. I'm sure it could be more efficient: for example you could vectorize the whole `push` part easily with a broadcast and a couple adds then write it all out with two 32-byte writes - but this is setup code outside of the critical region so "simplicity rules".